# does an onclick function go in model, view or controller?

Tags: model-view-controller, backbone.js, onclick

I am using backbone.js and trying to stay strict to the model-view-controller structure as I learn it. I have an onclick function for a link in one of my views that I am not sure where to put. Is the best place to keep this in the render function of the view?

Thanks

More specifically, the onclick performs a facebook login and then adds the user to my database if they are not currently in it. Don't know if this changes anything.

Here is what I think I will go with:

```
 var NewUserView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#window'),
    render: function(){
      // Render

      this.listeners();
    },
    listeners: function(){
      // onclick and other listeners
    }
  });
```

Comment: I'm a but fuzzy on frontend MVC, but i would say that the `onclick` handler should be in View, which then send request to (dispatches to ?) controller. As I see it, the frontend MVC is closer to [classical MVC](http://www.itu.dk/courses/VOP/E2005/VOP2005E/8_mvc_krasner_and_pope.pdf) design pattern, then to the MVC-inspired patterns that are usually used for web.

Comment: Have you read what the Backbone docs have to say about how Backbone relates to traditional MVC? http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-mvc

Comment: thanks, I hadn't read that before.. makes sense

Answer (score 1):

From the [Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-mvc):

> In Backbone, the View class can also be thought of as a kind of
>   controller, dispatching events that originate from the UI, with the
>   HTML template serving as the true view. We call it a View because it
>   represents a logical chunk of UI, responsible for the contents of a
>   single DOM element.

Here's the general way to handle events in Backbone:

```
var NewUserView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#window'),

    render: function() {
        // Render
    },

    events: {
        "click #facebookButton": "loginViaFacebook"
    },

    loginViaFacebook: {
        // Perform facebook login and add user to database
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want the link to appear? On `View` page right? So , you should keep it in the same `view` on which you want the link to appear.

But , if you are building an architecture rather than just a web application, then you should put the `onclick` function in some different file where you will keep all these function and then import them in the `view` as required or keeping them in separate files and `bundling` them for import on `view` page.

Comment: Alright, that is what I thought, too. I was just a little confused because the onclick has some logic in it, and I know that the view is supposed to be as logic-less as possible. More specifically, the onclick performs a facebook login and then adds the user to my database if they are not currently in it. Don't know if this changes anything.

Comment: @TroyCosentino: Updated my answer..and you should follow architecture style even if you are building small app[my recommendation]

Comment: alright, so not model, view, or controller.. just a file with functions in it? would you keep them in a class? or just like a list of functions

Comment: @TroyCosentino : I recommend you putting the logic in a separate class and use the class in onclick function, also keeping onclick function in a separate file. It will make your code modular and easier to track any error.

Comment: alright I think this makes sense.. I am going to see if anyone else weighs in before i choose an answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22094/discussion-between-troy-cosentino-and-bhushan-firake)

Answer (score -1):

Please make a file and write all the functions in that file and include that file in the your view file and use the onClick in the anchor tag. Please let me know if this make sense.